# User mapping - SharePoint migration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, migration, metalogix

We are going to migrate SharePoint 2013 to o365 using Metalogix. Okta is an identify provider for both environments ( we login with same IDs in both environments).

So, should we need to map users before migration?  If anybody having experience in migration then please help. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you have verified your Domain in Online Environment (Tenant) and have synchronized accounts with the same UPN like user.name@domain.com to Online, you don't need users mapping table.

This table is used only when you migrating from On-Premises to Online and the UPN is changed like:

- user.name@domain.com > user.name@domain.onmicrosoft.com

**I recommend you to do test migration and check everything, after test migration you will have checked permissions, proper created pages, structure and migrated documents.**